# how to I pass request response from one route to the other with express

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following express routes:

```
router.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/error", session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        var token = req.user.token;
        res.redirect("/getData?token=" + token);
    }
);

router.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
    var token = req.query.token;
  console.log(token)
request('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=' + token,  
function (error, response, body) {
          let views = []
   JSON.parse(body).items.forEach(view => {
            views.push({
              name: view.webPropertyId + ' - ' + view.name + ' (' + view.websiteUrl + ')'
            })
          })
res.redirect("/test?data="+ views);
  });
})

router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var testdata = req.user.data;
  console.log(testdata)
  res.send("ok")
})
```

I have two console log `console.log(token)` and `console.log(testdata)`. The first console log is working, the second one doesn't return me anything. I've tried many ways to pass the data from the request to the test page and I'm not able to to it. why?

Comment: Why not using middlewares https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html ?

Comment: Could you tell me why would I want to use a middleware here exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass the data through a query parameter, and then trying to read the data through `req.user`. This looks to me like just a syntax mistake. Change `req.user.data` with `req.query.data`.

Comment: Could you give me more details on the differences between req.user and req.query?

Comment: `req.query` comes from express and it's used to read a query parameter from the route's URL. `req.user` is an object that is used by passport.js to keep track of data related to the user who is making the request. In both cases this data is defined by the programmer, and not by a library or framework.

Comment: One more thing, `req.query` is defined by requests made on the front end, whereas `req.user` is defined by the server when the user makes a request that requires him to verify his identity. In your case, the server validates a token (package from the front-end containing potentially containing data about a user. I say potentially because it could contain any data in reality and this data MUST be verified by the server.), and then after validating, the server will usually move the data from the token data into something called `req.user`.

Comment: hum... ok very useful... I'm a bit lost now but I think this is very important for me to understand this clearly. I'll investigate it. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend just starting with routing basics before moving onto authentication with passport.js. Try implementing your own username and password without passport.js to get a decent idea of why it's a bad idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200415/discussion-between-simon-breton-and-anthony-yershov).

Comment: just to fix something I said that was incorrect, in this case req.user is actually defined by the passport strategy I believe.